# Does True Seeing see through Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wild-shape, vision-and-light

Since Wild Shape can't be dispelled, which implies that it's not "inherently magical", can the spell True Seeing allow someone to see through a Wild Shape transformation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Truesight can see through Wild Shape

The spell *true seeing* gives you truesight, the description of which says:

> perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic.

and Wild Shape says:

> [...] you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before.

Since the druid is transformed by magic (though not by a spell), truesight can see through it.

Note: *dispel magic* still doesn't work on wild shape, not because it is not magical, but because it's not a *spell*. Dispel magic has no effect on magic things that are not spells.

> Any *spells* of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I just found out that this is a duplicate question.  I'm upvoting, marking it as an answer, and closing the question.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil no worries! It happens. I *should* have looked before answering but I didn't remember it being asked before.